# Sum() + DCount() combination in SQL not producing correct results

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

How can I get the total number of Granny Smith apples? I have tried everything and nothing seems to work. This is a cross tab query and I'm trying to count the number of Granny_Smith apples in each shipping container.

MS Access 2007 Expression

```
Total_Green_Apples: Sum(DCount("[Apple_Type]","[Apples]","[Apple_Type]"='Granny_Smith'))
```

**SQL**

```
TRANSFORM Count(DCount("[Apple_Type]","[Apples]")) AS Apple_Type
SELECT Shipping.Container_number, Sum(DCount("[Apple_Type]","[Apples]","[Apple_Type]"='Granny_Smith')) AS Total_Green_Apples
FROM Shipping INNER JOIN Apples ON Shipping.ID = Apples.ID
GROUP BY Shipping.Container_number
PIVOT Apples.Apple_Type;
```

Please help.

Comment: No, the field names were changed for SO. Besides, it's summer :)

Comment: Can you give examples of what you get vs what you expect?

Comment: Basically, it's not applying the condition "[Apple_Type]"='Granny_Smith' because it's finding the Total of not only Granny Smith Apples, all of the Apple_Types. Never again will I change the names of my fields to "apples", it sounds stupid. But basically that's my problem with the Totals - it's finding the total of ALL apples and not just the ones I specify (Granny Smith)

Comment: Actually, I just decided to calculate the total in a MS Access report. For some reason this was a lot easier, even though the expression would have been the same. Oh well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you just need a count of all Granny Smith apples in all shipping containers?

I'm sort of guessing at your DB structure and here's what I come up with:

```
SELECT COUNT(Apples.ID) as Total_Green_Apples
FROM Shipping
    JOIN  Apples ON Apples.ID = Shipping.ID
WHERE Apples.Apple_Type = 'Granny Smith'
```

If you want the count of all Granny Smith apples in each container it'd be:

```
SELECT Shipping.ID, COUNT(Apples.ID) as Total_Green_Apples
FROM Shipping
    JOIN  Apples ON Apples.ID = Shipping.ID
WHERE Apples.Apple_Type = 'Granny Smith'
GROUP BY Shipping.ID
```

If you provide your table definitions I can tune the query.